# Restart adbd as shell user on a non-rooted device without rebooting after the "setprop" operation

Tags: adb, 4.1-jelly-bean, services

The `setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555` worked on my non-rooted device, now I need to restart `adbd` as the `shell` user :

```
$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ getprop ro.build.version.release                             
4.1.2
shell@android:/ $ getprop service.adb.tcp.port                                 

shell@android:/ $ setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555                            
shell@android:/ $ getprop service.adb.tcp.port                                 
5555
```

I tried this to restart `adbd`, but the PID of `adbd` didn't change :

```
shell@android:/ $ ps -C adbd
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
shell     161   1     4724   308   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd
shell@android:/ $ stop adbd
shell@android:/ $ start adbd                                                   
shell@android:/ $ ps -C adbd                                                    
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
shell     161   1     4724   308   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd
shell@android:/ $ exit
$ adb connect 192.168.2.27
failed to connect to '192.168.2.27:5555': Connection refused
```

Then I sent a `SIGHUP` to try and trigger a `adbd` restart, but all it did was to kill `adbd` and now I cannot connect via USB anymore :

```
shell@android:/ $ kill -SIGHUP 161
$ adb shell
error: device offline
```

So now I HAVE to reboot in order start `adbd` which I've accidentally killed.

After reboot I also tried `setprop ctl.restart adbd` but it didn't work :

```
shell@android:/ $ ps -C adbd
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
shell     176   1     4720   300   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd
shell@android:/ $ getprop ctl.restart

shell@android:/ $ setprop ctl.restart adbd
shell@android:/ $ getprop ctl.restart                                          

shell@android:/ $ ps -C adbd                                                   
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
shell     176   1     4720   300   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd
shell@android:/ $
```

Can you help me restart `adbd` on my non-rooted device without reboot ?

Comment: Disable and enable `USB Debugging` in Developer Options.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Great, just what I needed :) ! Can this also be done via a command line ?

Comment: `settings put global adb_enabled 0` and `settings put global adb_enabled 1`. `setprop ctl.restart adbd` should also work. Tag shows you are on JB where SELinux should not be a problem.

Comment: @IrfanLatif As you surely expected, the `settings put global adb_enabled 0` command got me disconnect before the next `settings put global adb_enabled 1` command got executed

Comment: @IrfanLatif Yes it does but I found this 14 minutes ago :) See my own [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219292/253353) at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific context of setting the adb tcp/ip port, the `adb tcpip 5555` command does restart the `adbd` service.

As one can see the PID of `adbd` is changed after the `adb tcpip` command :

```
$ adb shell ps | egrep -w "adbd|PID"
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
shell     3675  1     4720   300   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd
$ adb tcpip 5555
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555
$ adb shell ps | egrep -w "adbd|PID"
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
shell     3800  1     4720   300   ffffffff 00000000 S /sbin/adbd
```